# Why HttpRequestValidationException has 500 http error code instead of 400?

Tags: c#, http, iis, asp.net-mvc-5

When I tested my web-app based on MVC5 I found that `HttpRequestValidationException` returns 500 from `GetHttpCode()`.
I catch this exception during security testing of requests to the server. MVC performs request validation and throws this exception, I processed it in the `Application_Error` and got 500 code returned, but, in fact, if user passed wrong input to server I should return 400 error (bad request). so don't understand why the exception has 500 error. Where I am wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are four reasons why `500` might be considered more appropriate.

1. One is that it isn't clear when a `HttpRequestValidationException` happens who did the wrong thing. It could be that the user quite clearly sent something incorrect, but it's also possible that the server incorrectly rejected something that was perfectly fine. Considering that this is the default behaviour on many requests that *could* be malicious, it's probable that the majority of cases where its thrown in response to non-malicious requests (the user isn't actively trying to do the site harm) fall into this category. Hence it could either be something that should be consider 4xx or 5xx and 5xx is a good assumption (don't blame the client when you aren't sure it's the client's fault).
2. When it happens in a non-malicious case it generally needs attention from a developer, which is only sometimes true of the 4xx codes (a 404 might need developer-attention because the 404 was caused by a bad link on the same site, but it might not). The sort of feedback one gets from 500 responses is more appropriate.
3. The general model ASP.NET started with pretty much mapped all exceptions to 500 responses, which does make sense a lot of the time. MVC has (sensibly) replaced that with more exceptions that map to other error conditions, but `HttpRequestValidationException` predates MVC.

Now those points made, I can't say I agree with any of them. I'd still say that `HttpRequestValidationException` means a client error and if it was mis-identified as such, well it was still identified as such, so it's clearly a 400.

However, the final reason is:

4. While the description of 400 status in RFC 7231 would seem to quite clearly cover such requests, RFC 7231 was published in 2014. `HttpRequestValidationException` and the handling of it goes back to at least 2003, when RFC 2616 was the relevant RFC. Under the description of 400 in that RFC, 400 could be read as only relating to requests where the actual HTTP message was mal-formed. While some people did use 400 more generally as a catch-all "client did something wrong" response, it wasn't completely clear that doing so was correct.

Even this though gives a reason why 500 may have been a more appropriate reaction 1.5 years ago, not why it should remain. Changing it though would have backwards-compatibility implications so may not be a good idea.

Still, if a given application that you are writing makes conscious use of `HttpRequestValidationException` (rather than overriding entirely with your own validation that uses a different approach) then it's sensible to catch such exceptions and send a 400 rather than a 500.

Comment: great post! thank you. I send back 400 leveraging approach that @Ofiris mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

This is just how MVC treat `HttpRequestValidationException`, I don't like it as well but you can manually change it to a `BadRequest`:

```
protected void Application_Error()
{
    var lastError = Server.GetLastError();
    if (lastError is ArgumentException || lastError is HttpRequestValidationException)
    {
        Server.ClearError();
        Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
    }
}
```